# Plone:RedHat Linux Server Plone site client getting stop automatically

Tags: linux, plone, zodb, ploneformgen, plone-3.x

Problem : I setup my Plone site with 2 clients usign Redhat Linux server and used following commands to start them but Client2  is not working properly and automatically stop working manytimes

```
bin/plonectl server start
bin/plonectl client1 start
bin/plonectl client2 fg (In debug mode)
```

Please suggest me where i am doing mistake or what else i can do.

Comment: Well, a debug instance doesn't daemonize, so it would stop when you close the shell, is that what's happening for you?

Comment: right @UlrichSchwarz so what  can i do for this ..??

Comment: `fg` does at least two things I can think of: it duplicates the log to the terminal and it sets the internal flags that prevent combining resources, setting cache-headers on resources, etc. I'm strongly assuming you can do without the log (it's in `event.log` anyway and you want to log out)?

Answer (score 0):

This seems ugly (since you can't do it with a command-line switch), but in `client2`'s `/etc/zope.conf`, change the switch

```
debug-mode off
```

to

```
debug-mode on
```

(but beware that `zope.conf` is re-generated every time you run `buildout`.)

To always have it on, put

```
debug-mode = on
```

in your `buildout.cfg`'s section on client2.